# Pandas groupby does not return the expected output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a program that applies `pd.groupby().agg('sum')` to a bunch of different `pandas.DataFrame` objects. Those dataframes are all in the same format. The code works on all dataframes except for this dataframe (picture: df1) which produces funny result (picture: result1).

I tried:

```py
df = df.groupby('Mapping')[list(df)].agg('sum')
```

This code works for `df2` but not for `df1`.

[image: df1]

[image: result1]

The code works fine for other dataframes (pictures: df2, result2)

[image: df2]
[image: result2]

Could somebody tell me why it turned out that way for df1?

Comment: Your data have `str` type. So `'sum'` will concatenate all the strings together. Try to convert them to `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in `df1`, most of the `numeric` columns are actually `str`. You can tell by the commas (`,`) that delimit thousands. Try:

```py
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(",",""))
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x))
```

The first line removes the commas from all the second, third, etc. columns. The second line turns them to numeric data types. This could actually be a one-liner, but I wrote it in two lines for readability's sake.

Once this is done, you can try your `groupby` code.

It's good practice to check the data types of your columns as soon as you load them. You can do so with `df1.dtypes`.

Comment: Such a trivial problem by itself. I was generating all these dataframes using the same loop so I have no idea why this one in particular turns out to be strings. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the first dataframe is the commas in variables that should be numeric and i think that python is not recognizing the columns as numeric. Did you try to replace the commas?